# How do I call a nested JavaScript function properly

Tags: javascript, toggle

I'm trying to set up function a nested function that I can call throughout my script, but I keep getting "error undefined is not a function". Perhaps someone can help me with how to do this correctly.

First I set global my variables:

```
var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
var subject = document.getElementById('subject');
```

Then I create a show/hide function:

```
var toggleVis = function() {

    function showSomething() {
        trigger.classList.add("active");
        subject.classList.add("active");
    }

    function hideSomething() {
        trigger.classList.remove("active");;
        subject.classList.remove("active");
    }

}
```

Then I set my event listener:

```
trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {

    if ( subject.classList.contains("active") ) {
        toggleVis.hideSomething();
    }
    else {
        togglePicker.showPicker();
    }
});
```

The reason I'm trying to do it this way is that there will be other triggers for subject on the page that will need access to the show/hide functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the functions inside the function, they are out of scope, you could attach them as properties to the wrapping function, but it looks like you just need an object

```
var toggleVis = {
    showSomething: function() {
        trigger.classList.add("active");
        subject.classList.add("active");
    },
    hideSomething: function() {
        trigger.classList.remove("active");;
        subject.classList.remove("active");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `togleVis` variable is a function and not an `object` so you can't do `toggleVis.hideSomething()`. Try updating your code to :

```
var toggleVis = (function() {
    return {
        showSomething : function () {
            trigger.classList.add("active");
            subject.classList.add("active");
        },

        hideSomething : function () {
            trigger.classList.remove("active");;
            subject.classList.remove("active");
        }
    };

}());
```

With this `toggleVis` is now an object with two properties `showSomething` and `hideSomething` functions.